# Triggering the change of a <option> that is loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I have a hard time getting a simple event triggering to work with jquery. I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and don't intend to downgrade. One thing that I'm missing is the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) method which functionality is now built in the [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) function. Here is what I want to do:

I have some DOM that is loaded via AJAX into my page, it looks as follows:

```
    <select id="equip_new">
        <option value="1">Text 1</option>
        <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    </select>
```

Now I want to thrigger the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) function of the newly loaded selected options. In the old jquery I would use

```
    $('#equip_new').live('change', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
```

Now I need to use .delegate() but it doesn't trigger anything. My code looks like that:

```
    $('#equip_new').delegate('option', 'change', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to use delegate correctly to trigger code when changing the options in my select box that is loaded into the DOM via AJAX?

**Edit:** I just figured it out but want to give the hint to others:

You have to call the .delegate() method on existing elements above the AJAX loaded content. For example the $('body')

Also my event handler binding or delegation was wrong. I made it up to the following code:

```
    $('body').delegate('#equip_new', 'change', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
```

Everthing is fine now. Sometimes you need to explain stuff to others to understand what you do wrong.

Comment: Just bind/rebind event handlers to elements after ajax loading

Comment: You should use `on()` instead of the older `delegate` or `live`.

Comment: But .on() doesnt work for future elements if I read the documentation correctly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()` function. `.live()` is deprecated

```
$('#equip_new').on('change', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this guide live () replace with .on() function

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  the event delegation must be done on a parent element from the elements you want to watch events, like this:

```
$('#equip_new').parent().on('#equip_new', 'change', function(){
        alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Yes. If the parent exists when the .on() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian

.on() method will also work for future (dynamically created) elements. you just have to use it the way you are using deligate. however the .on() syntax is the new syntax that version 1.7 uses and it is meant to substitute .bind(), .delegate() and .live().

see the fiddle : 57BTd

if you use on() like this, if won't ever in any scenario. in fiddle instead of body tag you can give any class or id of your document that is not dynamically generated(any parent's element class or id).